# Complex polylines + onDraw method = very slow

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, draw, polyline

I have a map in which I want to draw a route between two `GeoPoints`. This is what I'm doing:

1- Get the json data from Google's server.
2- Parse the json data and get all encoded `polylines`.
3- Decode all encoded `polylines` and create a `List<GeoPoint>` with all of them.
4- Pass the list to draw it and `invalidate()` map.

When all done, I can see the route drawed on my map perfectly defined but the performance of the map has decreased **a lot**.

So my question is: Is there any other method so that the performance doesn't decrease without reducing the `GeoPoints`?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Get more performance data using the profiling tool in DDMS. That will reveal where the bottle-neck is exactly.

Comment: If the route is very long, the performance is worst, so I think that the problem is that the map cannot move fluidly the route. I've heared that the onDraw() method redraws constantly what it draws, but I don't think that's the problem because I only call the draw method once.

Comment: I am testing MapFragment, and drawing a Polyline on that... a line with about 600 points... and after I draw it, the map gets REALLY *really* slow, to the point of useless...